# What is the error in return statement in the following code of C++?

Tags: c++, return-type

```
Chain Chain::insert(int x) {
    ChainNode * current = first;
    ChainNode * ptr = new ChainNode;
    ptr->data = x;
    ptr->link = NULL;
    if(first != NULL) {
        while(current->link != NULL) {
            current = current->link;
        }
        current->link = ptr;
        return * this;
    }
    else {
        first = ptr;
        return * this;
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't work without adding '&' (reference) in return statement i.e. it gives wrong results. Here, Chain is a class used to implement linked list and ChainNode is another class which corresponds to Node of linked list.

Comment: What is the copy constructor of chain?

Comment: do you really want to return a copy of your chain? Or shouldn't your return type be `Chain &` so that to get a reference to your current chain?

Comment: Could you also provide a short snippet how you're using your class and explain what goes wrong?

Comment: @cerkiewny I am not using any special copy constructor.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example, so people can see the error for themselves.

Comment: @Hurzelchen Can you explain the meaning of `return * this`? And why should I use `Chain &` in function signature?

Comment: `return *this` is used to return a reference to the current object (most commonly used in the assignment operator `operator=()`). It gives you the option to continue to keep using your instance something like that `Chain c; c.insert(a).insert(b);`. The `Chain &` means that you get a reference to an instance and not a copy like `Chain` would give you.

Comment: Please add to your post, the definition of `Chain` class or structure.